# When a limited but working version of something is better

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

There is a Persian proverb ("**One habitable village is better than one hundred desolated towns**") which emphasizes that a limited and small-scale but working thing (e.g. a solution or an achievement) is much better than several ones that do not work or could not be leveraged.

Is there any equivalent proverb/idiom for that in English?

Comment: Something like "perfect is the enemy of good"  ?  Or "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush"  ?

Comment: @stolenmoment I think your second suggestion should be given as an answer. You'll easily be able to add a reference or two.

Comment: @stolenmoment, Your second suggestion can be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [**A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush**](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-bird-in-the-hand.html), indicating that actual success is preferred over a possible future gain.

> **Example Sentence:** If you invest this money you might make a fortune; *but a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush*.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of proverbs that might get near the sense of what you're going for:

[If it ain't broke, don't fix it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it)

> Leave something alone; avoid attempting to correct, fix, or improve what is already sufficient (often with an implication that the attempted improvement is risky and might backfire).
>
> *I know it’s an ugly-looking antenna, but you know what they say: If it ain’t broke, don’t fix it.*

---

Also, in computer science, we have the phrase, “premature optimization is the root of all evil”, from Donald Knuth's seminal [Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

---

Also, not a proverb, but the concept of the minimum viable product might be helpful. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product):

> A minimum viable product (MVP) is a product with just enough features to satisfy early customers, and to provide feedback for future product development.

Comment: Also from computing the KISS acronym (Keep It Simple, Safe) has a similar connotation. The older and more general version is 'don't gild the lily'.